# User Scenarios, Journeys, Problem Statements - Tools/Ways to organise multiple scenarios and storyboards

Tags: user-research, user-journey, scenarios, storyboard

While we're making sense of the research data, we may wish to aggregate that into a set of scenarios, storyboards, or problem statements.
I'm wondering if any of you does organise such outputs and, if so, do you use any tool at all for that purpose?

As far as I'm aware, there's nothing to help us with this organisational task, and I'm looking for ways to keep track of the different scenarios, journeys, and so on we produce.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain a bit further what you mean by "aggregating data into a set of scenarios...". How do the outputs/artifacts look like?

What we do is categorize research data with tags to give it a certain structure. Then we cluster related information to identify patterns. These clusters (which are basically a group of quotes and observations) could be similar to your outputs.

Since you asked for tools, we're using [Condens](https://condens.io/) for that.

Comment: They look like a narrative - in a form of a user scenario.